# How to get value of text box using name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get a box value using name attribute instead of id attribute in jquery
Thanks

Comment: RTFM! Seriously. jQuerys documentation is fantastic http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$('input[name="hello"]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="textfield123" value="something" />

<script>
var valueoftextfield = document.getElementsByName('textfield123')
</script>
```

do you need something like this ??